# Dynamically replace image source with jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, image, src, yelp

I'm trying to replace the default Yelp star rating image for businesses with one of my own. To do so I need to find the corresponding image source for each of the possible 5 images that could have loaded. And then, based on that I need to load in the proper image I've created.

```
<div id="starRating">
    <img src="http://yelp-star-1.png"/>
</div>
```

So, yelp-star-1.png would be replaced with my-star-1.png. So on and so forth. This is probably pretty simple, but I'm new to jQuery and everything I've found has not worked properly. Your expertise is very much appreciated!

Comment: Is there logic between the name of the file to be replaced and the replacement file name?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to find what the Yelp score is to set what your image should be. If so, I think you need to look into their API: http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/overview

Answer (score 14):

```
$("#starRating img").attr("src", "http://pathto/my-star-1.png")
```

EDIT

I think that you're asking how to dynamically replace the src based on what is there currently. So if there is some direct difference in strings, maybe try

```
var img = $("#starRating img");
img.attr("src", img.attr("src").replace("yelp", "my"));
```

Comment: The tricky part for me is that I have to use either my-star-1, my-star-2, my-star-3, my-star-4 or my-star-5 based on the image that gets loaded from Yelp. I'm having a hard time knowing how to find the yelp image that loads so that I can replace it with the correct image.

Comment: Are you asking how to do string replacement? You aren't being very clear.

Comment: Sounds like he doesn't know the names of the yelp img files... Use firebug to inspect them? Or in fact most browsers now?

Answer (score 5):

If you are just trying to do a basic replace without any pattern:

```
$('img[src="http://website.com/images/yelp-star-1.png"]').attr('src','http://website.com/images/my-star-1.png');
```

This could be used with images who have a src attribute starting with `http://website.com/images/yelp-star-`

```
$('img[src^="http://website.com/images/yelp-star-"]').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace("yelp", "my"));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

@GrayB gave me a good solution - this does not require you to know the absolute img src:

```
jQuery('.element img').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace("find_", "replace_"));
});
```